Ошибка 500 при открытии экспортного файла каталога в Битрикс
Всем привет! Задача внедрить фиды в яндекс веб-мастер. На сайте, который написан на 1c-Bitrix есть функция экспорта каталога, так раз таки для Яндекса yml. Посмотрел в интернете, как делается и правильно экспортируется, добавил новый профиль yandex-simple

И начал экспорт, на выходе получил что-то типо такого yandex_7645267234.php, странно почему php, ведь нужен yml, далее во документации в интернете нужно просто обратиться к файлу, открыть его перейдя по ссылке, который дал битркис, но по переходе у меня ошибка 500

Возникает вопрос, что делать, как внедрить фиды, если на сайте 2000+ товаров. Связано ли это с тем, что сайт по факту написан на vue.js и next.js, а Битрикс используется, как CMS и БД. Если ошибка в этом, то как быть? Очень прошу помочь

Вероятно, ошибка в настройках профиля yandex-simple, из-за чего он неправильно выставляет расширение у экспортного файла. Ну и из-за того, что у того расширение php, сервер его не выдаёт как файл, а пытается его выполнить как PHP и, соответственно, получает ошибку.

@ВикторКарев И как это исправить? Подскажите пожалуйста

Друзья, на 2024 стоит выгружать в профиле yandex, а не yandex-simple. У меня все заработало

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
